# How do I Scroll to a particular view within a ScrollView by tapping a button?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to automatically scroll to a particular view in a ScrollView on tap of a button. I know how to get it to work with ForEach views (there are examples of this online and on Stack overflow) but I cannot get it to work without the ForEach.

Here is an example of it working with a ForEach:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var shouldScrollToBottom = false

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Button("Scroll to Bottom") {
                    shouldScrollToBottom = true
                }
                .padding()

                ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(0..<50) { index in
                            Text("Item \(index)")
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                                .background(Color.blue)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .padding()
                                .id(index)
                        }
                    }
                    .onChange(of: shouldScrollToBottom) { scrollToBottom in
                        if scrollToBottom {
                            withAnimation {
                                scrollViewProxy.scrollTo(49, anchor: .bottom)
                            }
                            shouldScrollToBottom = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works.

But I want to do it with individual views (not with a ForEach).

Here is an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {


    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ScrollView {

                Button("Scroll to view 4") {

                }
                .padding()

                VStack {
                    Divider()
                    View1()
                    Divider()
                }

                VStack {
                    Divider()
                    View2()
                    Divider()
                }

                VStack {
                    Divider()
                    View3()
                    Divider()
                }

                VStack {
                    Divider()
                    View4()
                    Divider()
                }

                VStack {
                    Divider()
                    View5()
                    Divider()
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this view, how do I make it scroll to view 4 when the button is tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
func scrollTo<ID>(
    _ id: ID,
    anchor: UnitPoint? = nil
) where ID : Hashable
```

According to Apple document `id` play vital role here. So you must provide unique id for individual `View` So that `ScrollViewReader` can detect and scroll correctly to that `View`.

For Example: follow below code for you references

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
                Button("Scroll to Red View") {
                    scrollViewProxy.scrollTo("Red View", anchor: .bottom)
                }
                .padding()
                
                PlaceHolderView(color: .green)
                    .id("Green View")
                
                PlaceHolderView(color: .yellow)
                    .id("Yellow View")
                
                PlaceHolderView(color: .blue)
                    .id("Blue View")
                
                PlaceHolderView(color: .red)
                    .id("Red View")
                
                PlaceHolderView(color: .orange)
                    .id("Orange View")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PlaceHolderView: View {
    let color: Color
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(color)
            .frame(height: 350)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great. This works. Is there a way to implement the Scrolling animation into this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not fundamentally different from what you'd do with a `ForEach`. Just give your views an `id`, and refer to the view you want to scroll to using that `id`.

```
VStack {
    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        ScrollView {
            
            Button("Scroll to view 4") {
                // pass the id of the destination view to scrollTo
                // wrap this with withAnimation if you like
                proxy.scrollTo(4)
            }
            .padding()
            
            Text("One")
                .frame(height: 200)
                .id(1)
            Text("Two")
                .frame(height: 200)
                .id(2)
            Text("Three")
                .frame(height: 200)
                .id(3)
            Text("Four")
                .frame(height: 200)
                .id(4)
            Text("Five")
                .frame(height: 200)
                .id(5)
        }
    }
}
```

Technically, if you are only scrolling to the fourth view, you don't need to add `id`s for the other views at all.

The `id` can be any `Hashable` thing. It doesn't have to all be `Int`s.

Comment: That's great. This works. Is there a way to implement the Scrolling animation into this?

Comment: @mbby like I said in the comments, “wrap `scrollTo` with `withAnimation` if you like, just like the first code snippet (the one using `ForEach`) in your question. Did you not examine that code?